# Is it possible to use JMeter with Digest Authentication?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, digest

I am VERY new to jMeter but I'm trying to create a performance test for a web application I built.

The only problem is that the server is behind a Digest Authentication form and I know that jMeter doesn't support this type of Authentication directly, is there a way I can manipulate the HTTP Header Manager to handle Digest Authentication? I'm very new to this, so I don't know how to properly create this header information if it was even possible. Can anyone offer any help? Thanks.

Is there perhaps another solution out there?

Thank you for any responses.

SOLUTION EDIT:
I was making a fools error. For future readers, when you enter your Base URL in the HTTP Authorization Manager make sure you enter 'example.com'; rather than 'www.example.com'. Also I left the Domain and Realm blank and it still worked with only the Base URL, username, and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter supports DIGEST authentication using [Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

If Kerberos is used in your authentication, you can give nightly build a try as it is now implemented.

Comment: You are correct, and I discovered I was making a fools error. For future readers of this comment (yes I'm leaving it despite it making me look so incompetent) when you enter your Base URL make sure you enter 'http://www.example.com' rather than 'www.example.com'